# How can I check if a Doctrine reference is valid?

Tags: php, doctrine

I try to get the reference of a documents:

```
$result = $this->em->getReference('App\Entity\Documents', 522);
```

But I get the error message:

```
Entity of type 'App\Entity\Documents' for IDs id(522) was not found
```

Is there a way to check if the reference is valid or initialized true or if the document with the specific id exists?

Something like:

```
if($this->em->getReference('App\Entity\Documents', 522) == true){
 $result = $this->em->getReference('App\Entity\Documents', 522);
} else {
$result = "";
}
```

Comment: get reference is meant to reduce the amount of db queries (and data in memory). however, you probably can `$exists = $this->em->getRepository(Documents::class)->count(['id' => 522]) == 1`, i don't see the relevance for the formbuilder yet ... how is that relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getReference()` does not cause a lookup in the DB. you can use `find()`, like this

```
if($this->em->find('App\Entity\Documents', 522) !== null)
```